# PhoneGap Images

Tags: android, cordova

I am currently creating an `Android` application with `Phonegap` and I am unable to insert images to my project. I have saved my .png file in different directories and still only a question mark shows up where my image should be. I can not use images from a URL either.

Comment: just give the path right  in the js, and make sure its inside the assets folder..

Answer (score 8):

To use a local image try the following.

Put your image in the /assets/www folder of the project

Then set the image tag as follows:

```
<img src="../www/myimage.png">
```

Yes, I realize this should be the identical to setting the src to "myimage.png". I cannot say the reason why this might work, but I had the exact same problem with local images on Phonegap and this fixed the issue for me. If you have them in a subdirectory, you can try adding this on to the path:

```
<img src="../www/mydir/myimage.png">
```

I also found the following syntax worked, maybe a little less clumsy looking:

```
<img src="./myimage.png">
```

Or

```
<img src="./mydir/myimage.png">
```

This was all on Android 4.0 unfortunately, I do not know for earlier versions of the OS

Answer (score 4):

For me i got the solution by adding dot before the "images" folder like this

```
<img src="./images/bg4.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a mistake I've done quite a lot.
If you add `.js` files to your index.html and use images in them, you need to calculate your images path from the `index.html` page and not from the `.js` file because the `.js` file will be interpreted in `index.htm`

For example, put all your images in a `img`/ folder next to index.html and then when you're using one of these images just do

```
<img src="img/YOU_IMG.png" />
```

Comment: I've got the same problem as the OP. But the images are in the correct place because they work fine in the web browser. It's only when I run it though the emulator do they not show...

Comment: Then create a new post. It'll be easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about images in PhoneGap applications - they're web applications. If you point a desktop browser to your project folder and open the index.html, what happens with  your images? If they don't show up there, they're not going to show up in the PhoneGap application.

Comment: But this is untrue as (at least in my case) the images do show in a browser but not in the phone emulator